# javascript chess board string concatenation

Tags: javascript

Why isn't my code working Its suppose to print a chessboard but it seams like its only printing the newline characters?

I am relatively new to JavaScript. Its suppose to determine if the line is number is even or odd and depending and then add  '`#`' and  ' ' to the board string. If the program is at the end of a row it adds a '`\n`'.

```
var width = 8, height = 8;

let board = "";


for(let n=0; n<height; n++)
{
  if(height % 2 === 0)
  {
    for(let i=0; i<width ; i++)
    {
      if(width%2===0)
      {
        board = board + " ";
      }
      else {
        board = board + "#";
      }
      if (i =width-1)
      {
        board = board + "\n";
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    for(let i=0; i<width ; i++)
    {
      if(width%2===0)
      {
        board += "#";
      }
      else {
        board += " ";
      }
      if (i =width-1)
      {
        board = board + "\n";
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(board);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two things you're doing wrong :

- At one place in your code, you're doing an `i = width - 1` assignment where you should be doing a `i == width - 1` comparison
- At a few places in your code, you're comparing a value with `width` or `height`, where should should be comparing with `n` or `i`

#### Fixed code :

```
var width = 8, height = 8;
let board = "";

for(let n=0; n<height; n++)
{
  if(n % 2 === 0)
  {
    for(let i=0; i<width ; i++)
    {
      if(i%2===0)
      {
        board += " ";
      }
      else {
        board += "#";
      }
      if (i == width-1)
      {
        board += "\n";
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    for(let i=0; i<width ; i++)
    {
      if(i%2===0)
      {
        board += "#";
      }
      else {
        board += " ";
      }
      if (i == width-1)
      {
        board += "\n";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cxuthwz5/1/))

---

#### After some further improvements :

```
let width = 8, height = 8, board = "";

for(let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        if((i % 2 === 0 && j % 2 === 0) || (i % 2 !== 0 && j % 2 !== 0)) {
            board += " ";
        } else {
            board += "#";
        }
    }
    board += "\n";
}
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cxuthwz5/3/))

Answer (score -1):

You're comparing height & width, that always are the same, instead of loop variable i.

Here a working sample, migrated from comments by popular petition...

```
 function board() 
 { 
    var x,y; 
    var board = ""; 

    for (y=1;y<9;y++) 
      for (x=1;x<9;x++) 
         board +=(x+y)%2 == 0? "W":"-"; board += (x%8)==0? "\n":""; 

    console.log(board); 
  }
```

Comment: Also `i =width-1` will always be true, becuase it is not a comparision, rather an assignment.

Comment: I changed it to i === width - 1 and its still only giving newline characters

Comment: See first comparision you're realizing :  if(height % 2 === 0) .. and if(width%2===0)...

Comment: nvm I applied both DvTr and Fabian N. suggestion and it works thank you soooo much

Comment: Although finished, take a look at this version :       function board()
            {
                var x,y;
                var board = "";
                
                for (y=1;y<9;y++)
                for (x=1;x<9;x++)
                {
                    board +=(x+y)%2 == 0? "W":"-";                            
                    board += (x%8)==0? "\n":"";
                }
                
                console.log(board);
            };

Comment: Why don't you just update your answer instead of adding comments?

Comment: Because response of the question 'why isn't my code working' was the answer itself. All the other is comments, as done. Why the hell you downvote? Response is correct, and so Fabian's & mine comments...